# Парсинг веб страницы с JavaScript без использования selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно получить html-код страницы после срабатывания скриптов. Это неплохо получается с webriver`ом, но к сожалению, использовать его не очень удобно для задачи, т.к. использует дополнительно браузер.
Есть ли какие-нибудь альтернативные модули в python, для рендера динамичных страниц и получения после этого html-кода?

Comment: Даже если бы такой модуль и был, он бы в итоге всё равно оказался эквивалентен браузеру

Comment: Пусть будет эквивалентен, но не использует другое ПО

Comment: А что не так с другим ПО?